# Travis detecting Ruby default settings in a Django project

Tags: django, python-3.x, github, travis-ci

I have a Django project that I want to test continuously using `Travis-CI`. The problem is that every time I run a build in Travis it fails because a `rake` command of *ruby*.

I have already changed my `travis.yml` a hundred times but it's not working. I leave my last *travis.yml* that is in the same directory that my `requirements.txt`

```
language: python 
python: 
  - "3.5"
  - "3.6"
  - "3.7"
cache: pip
services: 
  - sqlite3
env: 
  - DJANGO=2.2.4 DB=sqlite3
install:
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
before_script: 
  - sqlite3  - e 'create database test;' -u root
script: 
  - python manage.py makemigrations
  - python manage.py migrate
  - python manage.py test
```

The output I get from travis is this:

```
rvm

$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master ...
1.01s$ rvm use default

ruby.versions

$ ruby --version

No Gemfile found, skipping bundle install

0.21s$ rake

rake aborted!

No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)

/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'

/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'

/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)

The command "rake" exited with 1.

Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `travis.yml` to `.travis.yml`.

See more at [Getting started](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/tutorial/#to-get-started-with-travis-ci) and [Building a Python projects](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/)

Comment: I did it but it still takes the default configuration for ruby instead my .travis.yml

Comment: May I see the project ?

Comment: I created pull request, build run python. Here is build https://travis-ci.org/tru17189/Ingeneria-de-Software-2-/jobs/578208200

Comment: Also check my pull request https://github.com/tru17189/Ingeneria-de-Software-2-/pull/1 . It also run python build